# is there a way to add only latest values?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pygsheets

I am importing data from excel to google sheets using python code.
Everytime I run the script previously updated records getting over write. Please help me with how can I retain previously added values and added only new values.

Comment: Without code, it is difficult to determine a solution. Please provide a small script that illustrates the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use openpyxl only to modify an existing excel. Any other packages like xlwt xlsxwritter can only write a new file, and I am surprised that it does not throw an error as you are trying to write an existing file. If you are using pandas, try search openpyxl page to embed it in pandas.